# Why does Laravel return BadMethodCallException on API request?

Tags: laravel, axios

I am unable to get my `Axios` api calls to work. They connect but I keep getting bad method call exceptions.

**Axios**

```js
axios.get('/api/test')
     .then(response => {
         const data = response.data;
         console.log(data);
     });
```

**APIController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class APIController extends Controller
{
    //
    private function test(Request $request)
    {

        // test
        return response()->json(new \stdClass());
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\APIController;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('test',  [APIController::class, 'test'])->name('test');
```

**Error***

```
Bad Method Call
Did you mean App\Http\Controllers\APIController::test() ?
```

I have tried clearing all caches but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Api function `test` is private, it needs to be public.

Comment: Sigh! I must be too tired and should take a break. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @matt don’t beat yourself up about it, we’ve all been there :)